# Receiving BaseEncodingException when signing transaction using TestNet : Invalid Input Length

Tags: transactions, java-sdk, signer, encoding

Sending from Account A to B is not working in my implementation. The docs provided by stellar for Java are straight forward but I have been receiving a BaseEncodingException when trying to sign the transaction. My code is identical to that on the Java docs for stellar, am I missing something here?

Also, checks are done on both accounts to ensure they are not-null and have proper funds for the transaction to go through.

```
KeyPair destination = KeyPair.fromAccountId(request.getSource());
        KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(ServerInfo.PRIVATE_KEY_MAIN_ACCOUNT);
        Transaction trns = null;
        try {
            AccountResponse sourceAccount = checkForFunds(request);
            trns = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount, Network.TESTNET)
                    .addOperation(new PaymentOperation
                            .Builder(destination.getPublicKey().toString(), new AssetTypeNative(), request.getAmount())
                            .build())
                    .addMemo(Memo.text("Test Transaction"))
                    .setTimeout(180)
                    .setOperationFee(100)
                    .build();
            System.out.println(".buildTransaction() - transaction created: " + trns.hashCode());
            // Sign the transaction to prove you are actually the person sending it.
            trns.sign(source);
            return trns;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the account id encoding of the public key to the `PaymentOperation` builder. In other words, instead of passing `destination.getPublicKey().toString()` to the builder you should be passing in `destination.getAccountId()`. However, looking at your entire code snippet, it seems like you already have the destination account id.

I believe your code can be simplified to:

```java
        String destination = request.getSource());
        KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(ServerInfo.PRIVATE_KEY_MAIN_ACCOUNT);
        Transaction trns = null;
        try {
            AccountResponse sourceAccount = checkForFunds(request);
            trns = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount, Network.TESTNET)
                    .addOperation(new PaymentOperation
                            .Builder(destination, new AssetTypeNative(), request.getAmount())
                            .build())
                    .addMemo(Memo.text("Test Transaction"))
                    .setTimeout(180)
                    .setOperationFee(100)
                    .build();
            System.out.println(".buildTransaction() - transaction created: " + trns.hashCode());
            // Sign the transaction to prove you are actually the person sending it.
            trns.sign(source);
            return trns;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
```

---

The difference between `destination.getAccountId()` and `destination.getPublicKey().toString()` is that `destination.getPublicKey()` returns the underlying bytes of the Ed25519 public key. When you call `toString()` on a byte array in Java it will invoke the default `toString()` implementation which returns something like `[B@1f57539`:

```java
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

`destination.getAccountId()` will return an ASCII encoding of the public key. The specifics of the encoding are described here: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0023.md

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Transaction works now, Cheers!